# Info button not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an info button in my HTML form and I am following code I found in https://codepen.io/EasyBoarder/pen/Lkzzjy for that.

I copied exactly same code in my html and css files but I am not seeing the (i) icon.

HTML

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="info">
        <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
        <span class="extra-info">
             A little column extra info. Aaand just a little bit more
        </span>
    </div><br />
    <span>Hover me!</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.extra-info {
  display: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
}

.info:hover .extra-info {
  display: block;
}

.info {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.info:hover {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  width: 315px;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

I am seeing this in my HTML form now :

[image]

Can it be because class icon-info-sign is not declared in CSS file ? Or maybe the href link is not up to date ?
If so, how is it working in the code sample online ?

Thank you !

EDIT :

I added the css config to global.scss.
[image]
However, in F12 mode, I don't see this CSS file was taken into account. It is only seeing loading.css file which I did not modify.

P.S code has been generated by Jhipster.

Comment: visit https://fontawesome.com/ and signup, create your own link there to use font-awesome for free and insert the new <i> element you can find under https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery, for more help they also have a documentation page

Comment: How did you include that css in your html ?

Answer (score 0):

The `.icon-info-sign` icon depends on Font Awesome's CSS. In this example it works correctly:

```css
body {
  background-color: #CECECE !important;
  margin: 20px !important;
}

* {
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.extra-info {
  display: none;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
}

.info:hover .extra-info {
  display: block;
}

.info {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.info:hover {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  width: 315px;
  text-align: left !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="info">
    <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
    <span class="extra-info">A little column extra info. Aaand just a little bit more</span>
  </div>
  <br />
  <span>Hover me!</span>
</div>
```

Have you checked in your browser's Developer Tools if the CSS has been included correctly?

Comment: Thank you @Alessio Cantarella.

I edited my question with a coupe of screenshots. In F12 mode, I don't see that the css file I changed is being taken into account ....

Comment: The "global" CSS file is taken into account in the html. When I run the code snippet on https://codepen.io/EasyBoarder/pen/Lkzzjy (and as you shared previously yourself), it is working fine. I am still not able to understand why it is not when I include it in my html within my project ?